# Can PyCharm suggest available methods?

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

PyCharm Professional does not suggest methods while typing (for any library).

For example, in the screenshot below, I would expect to see methods I can call on `service` in the autosuggest popover (like I would in WebStorm or PhPStorm). I only get "not", "par" and "main" every single time.

[image]

Everything is enabled in settings in accordance to all the other posts on the topic. See code completion settings below:

[image]

Is something off or is this just not a feature like with Javascript or PHP? Below is an example for PhpStorm which shows me all the methods I can call on `$response`. I want to achieve the same thing in PyCharm.

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Sure [it can](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html). Check to see if those modules have been [indexed](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/indexing.html).

Comment: @InSync I invalidated caches, restarted the IDE, re-indexed everything, and still no suggestions.

Comment: Did you check Editor / General / Code Completion settings?

Comment: @FN_ I updated the post with a screenshot.

Comment: Maybe PyCharm can not determine what the return type of build() is. If thats the case, use python type hints https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe PyCharm can not determine what the return type of build() is. If thats the case, use [python type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import Resource
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

service: Resource = build(...)
```